# fread не читает данные из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть функция создания бинарного файла с числами и чтения из него. Также функция чтения чисел из переменного количества бинарных файлов которая сливает их в один, и возвращает указатель на строку в которой имя этого файла содержится. (Load_data)
Проблема в том, что функция чтения из бинарного файла отказывается читать данные из файла имя которого вернула функция Load_data.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "vnsort_bin_dec.h"
#include "vnsort_bin_inc.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 20

using namespace std;

char* Load_data(const char* path, ...)
{
    int i = 0, t;
    char *str = new char[N];

    FILE* f, *a;

    va_list path_ptr; //Объявление списка переменных аргументов

    const char* path_tmp = path; // инициализация указателя
    va_start(path_ptr, path); // инициализация списка переменных аргументов

    // создание файла
    puts("Введите имя файла!");
    gets_s(str, N);


    if ((a = fopen((char*)str, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Файл %s не открывается", a);
        system("pause");
        //return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            f = fopen(path_tmp, "rb");
            fseek(f, 0L, 0);

            while (fread(&t, sizeof(int), 1, f))
            {
                // записываем все числа в один файл
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(int), 1, a);
                if (feof(f)) break;
                i++;
            }

            path_tmp = va_arg(path_ptr, const char*);

        } while (path_tmp);
    }

    puts("Данные загружены!");

    return str;
}

int creat_bin(char *a) // создание файла данных, ввод чисел с клавиатуры
{
    FILE* A;
    int n;

    if ((A = fopen(a, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Файл %s не открывается", a);
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Введите %d целых чисел: ", 5);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            scanf_s("%d", &n);
            fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, A);
        }
        fclose(A);
    }
}

int read_bin(char* a) // чтение файла данных
{
    FILE* A;
    int n;

    if ((A = fopen(a, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Файл %s не открывается", a);
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //fseek(A, 0L, 0);
        while (fread(&n, sizeof(int), 1, A))
            cout << n << " "; 
        fclose(A);
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    char *str;
    
    str = Load_data("t1", "t2", NULL);

    read_bin(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли закрыть файлы `f` и `a` в функции `Load_data()`. Ввод/вывод буферизированный, по-этому данные в `a` не попали.

```
char* Load_data(const char* path, ...)
{
    int i = 0, t;
    char *str = new char[N];

    FILE* f, *a;

    va_list path_ptr; //Объявление списка переменных аргументов

    const char* path_tmp = path; // инициализация указателя
    va_start(path_ptr, path); // инициализация списка переменных аргументов

    // создание файла
    puts("Введите имя файла!");
    gets(str);


    if ((a = fopen((char*)str, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Файл %s не открывается", a);
        system("pause");
        //return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            f = fopen(path_tmp, "rb");
            fseek(f, 0L, 0);

            while (fread(&t, sizeof(int), 1, f))
            {
                // записываем все числа в один файл
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(int), 1, a);
                if (feof(f)) break;
                i++;
            }

            fclose(f); //НУЖНО ЗАКРЫТЬ!
            path_tmp = va_arg(path_ptr, const char*);

        } while (path_tmp);

        fclose(a); //НУЖНО ЗАКРЫТЬ!
    }

    puts("Данные загружены!");

    return str;
}
```

И ещё `return` забыли в функциях `int creat_bin()` и `int read_bin()`.

Comment: спасибо огромное! несколько часов не мог найти